# How can I create large random vectors efficiently, without resorting to loops?

Tags: matlab

Problem statement:- I want to create 50 instances of a vector(1 Dimension) which contains random real numbers(float). The array size(1 dimension) will be say 30 thousand.How do i proceed so that the overhead is minimum or complexity is minimum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
N = 30000; %// length of your vectors
I = 50; %// number of instances
v = rand(I, N);
```

In the example above you will generate a matrix, in which every row is a single vector. Random numbers are generated with uniform distribution (for Gaussian distribution, use `randn`).

If you need to create every instance separately use a loop:

```
for i=1:I
    v = rand(1, N);
    %// do something with v
end
```

But I wouldn't use that if I were you (it is slower and IMHO less clear).

**EDIT**:
Regarding your question under Mau's answer:
No, you don't need to index it on your own. Let Matlab do it for you.
For example, if you need to repeat following operation 50 times:

```
 x1 = sigma*y + beta * vect1;
 ...
 x50 = sigma*y + beta * vect50;
```

assuming `y` is a vector of size 1x30000, you can compute it in one line:

```
X = sigma*repmat(y, 50, 1) + beta * rand(50, 30000);
```

explanation:
every row is a single vector you wanted to compute:

```
X(1,:) = x1;
...
X(50,:) = x50;
```

`repmat(y,50,1)` repeats your `y` vector 50 times in first dimension (rows)

Comment: @Gacek,is this equivalent to for i=1:30000 for j=1:50
v(i)(j)=rand();
% then i use the first element of v for some computation
x=sigma*y+v*beta;
end
end

Eventhough this is crude.

Comment: @SKM: nope, you misunderstood me. example with `for` loop was given to show you second way of generating such vectors. See my update, I hope it clearly shows the solution of your problem. I know it could be somehow difficult at the beginning, but try to forget about the loops when using Matlab.

Comment: @Gacek.....would you be kind enough to tell me how to convert your answer to an m file so that the above code becomes a function which will be called based on varying the variables I and N in order to plot the x's I number of times?

Comment: @SKM: well, to plot these 50 vectors you don't need to index them one by one as well. Just use `plot(X')` (big `X` - the matrix; `'` means transposition of the matrix). 

To create m-file containing your function, see this documentation page: http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/function.html

Answer (score 4):

Create a 50x30k matrix of random values

```
values = rand(50, 30000)
```

then each row will be a 30k-values random vector

```
 aVector = values(3,:)  % Row 3, all columns
```

Comment: Let me make myself clear.say the vector is vect1,vect2.....,vect50 each containing 30 thousand real numbers/float.These will be substituted in an equation say x1=sigma*y+vect1(i)*beta where sigma and beta are constants. Dont i need a loop to get 30,000 values of x?
something like this..for i=1:50
for j=1: 300000
x(j)=sigma*y+vect(i)(j)*beta;
end
end

Comment: No, you can write vectorized code that uses the big matrix (and runs faster). See: http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1109.html#operators

Comment: @Mau.Would you kindly explain the implication of 3 in values(3,:) ?Thank you

Comment: @SKM When you index a matrix in matlab with m(i, j) you get the element at row i, column j. If you substitute : for one of the indices you get either all rows or all columns (like in the example).

Comment: This im aware but why did you choose third row?just for example or does it have something specific meaning?